# Why is an element jumping out of it's container when position: fixed is added to the element in (Safari only)

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I am using a simple jQuery plugin called [Stacks](http://dev.michael-smedley.co.uk/stacks/) for making my section headlines fixed when the header hits the section headline. The plugin will add classes like `.fixed` and `.absolute` I am then using a CSS transition to resize the section headline when the user begins to scroll past the headline a bit.

This is working in every browser I have tested on (even IE8) except for Safari. It doesn't seem to matter what version of Safari either as it breaks on all of them. The headline seems to jump out of the container and it's background almost completely disappears.

[Screenshot that compare the bug (imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkHnY.jpg)

I'm a JavaScript noob, so I'm prepared to be told how I'm doing it wrong, but any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    if($(window).width() >= 768){
        $('#tour-headline').waypoint(function() {
            $('#tour-headline').removeClass("large").addClass("small");   
        });
        $('#news-headline').waypoint(function() {
            $('#news-headline').removeClass("large").addClass("small");   
        });
        $('#music-headline').waypoint(function() {
            $('#music-headline').removeClass("large").addClass("small");   
        });

        $('body').stacks({
            body: 'section',
            title: '.section-headline',
            offset: 110,
            margin: 0
        });
    }
});
```

Here's my CSS

```
.section-headline {
background: #e1eaf0;
border-bottom: 8px #fcef7f solid;
}

.section-headline.small h3 {
padding: 10px 0;
font-size: 16px;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s; 
transition: all 0.4s;
}

.section-headline.large h3 {
padding: 25px 0;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s; 
transition: all 0.4s;
}

.fixed{ 
position: fixed;
top:110px;
left:0;
right:0;
z-index:90;
}

.absolute{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom:0;
z-index:91;
bottom: 0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

section{
position: relative;
}
```

You can view the site yourself at dollypartonentertainment.com

**EDIT:** I found my problem! I was using `transition` on `.section-headline` a few dozen lines earlier in the file - I'm not entirely sure why it would cause it to react the way it did, but that was it!

Comment: If you could set up a fiddle / codepen reproducing the issue it would make solving this issue much easier.

Comment: Good advice @badAdviceGuy, I'll put this together.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so posting my comment here... Not sure if this helps, but try adding this, wich prevents stuff from popping out of div's

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I added `overflow: hidden;` to `.section-headline` which somewhat changed the way it behaves in Safari, but it's still popping out of the container.

Comment: make sure you have correct ending of your divs and such <div>..</div>. I use Firebug in firefox to check for errors.